# Dropdown empty option

Tags: drop-down

in order for my client to have the choice of selecting options or not, I entered an empty (blank) option in a dropdown field.

In the frontend, I use this code:

```
{% if entry.dropdownFieldHandle|length %}
<dt>Title</dt>
<dd>{{ entry.dropdownFieldHandle }}</dd>
{% endif %}
```

The problem is even if the client chooses the blank option, it still makes the code appear.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the client selects an empty value you probably will get an empty value back.

Try this:

```
{# Make sure we have a value #}
{% if entry.dropdownFieldHandle != "" %}
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>{{ entry.dropdownFieldHandle }}</dd>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can also just do `{% if entry.dropdownFieldHandle %}` (see [`if` tag docomantation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html)).

Comment: ^Ah yes. Even cleaner :)